# Ruby on Rails Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-postgres

I just tried to push my app to heroku but when I go to run heroku run rake db:migrate it says, "Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later." Any ideas as to what I can do?

Comment: Um...try again later?

Comment: Thnks? don't know if this is sarcastic but its been 10 hours now and no success

Comment: Have you tried login into a bash session? something like `heroku run bash`

Comment: @Pagaley12 My earlier comment was not (entirely) sarcastic. Sometimes Heroku services go down and things don't work for a time. You are going to have to provide more information, or contact Heroku support.

Comment: I've just tried running heroku bash and got the same answer

Comment: From the information you have provided, there is no possible way to determine the problem.

Comment: What else should I include

Comment: when you configured your DB, was it setup in sqlite3 or postgreSQL? Sqlite3 is not supported in Heroku. you'll have to build your schema using postgreSQL.. Let me see if I can post an example as an answer for you... unless you are already migrating your DB in postgreSQL?

Answer (score -1):

From the Heroku site, itself...

> "*SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk. While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every 24 hours.
>
> Even if Heroku’s disks were persistent, running SQLite would still not be a good fit. Since SQLite does not run as a service, each dyno would run a separate running copy. Each of these copies need their own disk backed store. This would mean that each dyno powering your app would have a different set of data since the disks are not synchronized.
>   Instead of using SQLite on Heroku you can configure your app to run on Postgres.*"

Additional troubleshooting...

> > **Getting a SQLite error even though it is not in the Gemfile**
> >
> > If you’ve removed the gem `sqlite3` line from your Gemfile and are still getting errors while deploying to Heroku it is likely that another gem you are using has `sqlite3` as a dependency. To help find the source of this dependency look in your `Gemfile.lock` for `sqlite3`. Find the gem that has `sqlite3` as a dependency and remove it from your Gemfile. Once you’ve done this run bundle install and ensure that `sqlite3` no longer exists in your `Gemfile.lock`.

**[Running Rails on PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage)**

> PostgreSQL database can be used by any language and framework, [this section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage) covers how to connect to it through the Ruby on Rails framework. It is important that you use the same database in production as in development, so you will need to install the PostgreSQL database locally.

---

If you are starting a new Rails app, you can make `postgres` the default database by running:

```
rails new -d postgresql
```

This will install the `pg` gem in your Gemfile and write the correct config/database.yml configuration locally.

If you have a pre-existing Rails app, or you ran the rails new command without the `-d postgresql` flag you can convert your application manually.

First open your Gemfile and remove this line:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Replace with this line:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Then run bundle install.

Next you will need to convert your config/database.yml. Open the existing file, which might look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

You will need to change the adapter from

```
adapter: sqlite3
```

to this:

```
adapter: postgresql
```

Note the adapter name is `postgresql` not `postgres` or `pg`. You will also need to change the `database:` to a custom name. A final version might look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Once you’ve installed the `pg` gem and migrated your `config/database.yml` file you will need to create your database and run any pre existing migrations against it:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Now you need to `$ git add .` and `$ git commit -m postgres` then you will be good to go. Now when you push to Heroku using Rails a development grade postgres instance will be provisioned and connected to your app automatically.

**If you’re not using Rails, you may need to manually add the postgres addon by running**

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

Answer (score -2):

This likely means you hit your free dyno rate limit